# Can't connect to dynamically created contract in Mix

Tags: solidity, mix

I have an instance of a Gizmo contract created by a Factory but I can't hook into it from JS.

`> gizmoInst = web3.eth.contract(gizmoABI).at(gizmoAddr)

Error: INVALID_PARAMS: Invalid method parameters (invalid name and/or type) recognised`

Any clues?

Comment: I can't connect to any contracts using the web3.eth.contract methods.

Comment: did you deploy it on test or private network and try to access it on main, sorry to ask this dumb question but it happened to me once ;)

Comment: I'm trying this in Mix console so it's just Mix's sealed blocks.  I haven't deployed anything to the chains yet because I can't get past this issue.

Answer (score 2):

The error was that I was passing a stringified ABI to web3.eth.contract(ABI) and not an array object.

Answer (score 1):

if you're using Mix the access to the contract is just done using contracts["contractName"]
.
if you follow the tutorial [here](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Mix:-The-DApp-IDE), they write a contract called **Rating**.
the way to access it in the javascript code is the following :

```
var res = contracts["Rating"].contract.ratings(param);
```

Si I'd try to access it through `contracts["Gizmo"]` or whatever name you called it.

Comment: The problem is that Gizmo is dynamically created by a Factory contract and so doesn't exist in the contracts[] object.

Comment: did you have successfully mined it after creation ?

Comment: yes and the Factory contract can see it fine and read it's publics